# Arrays in java (First two values will be a string and the last one will be int )

Tags: java

I would like to achieve the following array in java.

```
$values = array();

$values[]['monthName'] = 'April'
$values[]['Year'] = '2014'
$values[]['value'] = 4658;
```

Comment: you can't index array with String in java (only int)

Comment: You can use an array of Objects and mixup `Integer` and `String`

Comment: @MarounMaroun : its a php. I want to do it in java

Comment: How about defining a new type using the class keyword?

Comment: Is this a 2D array? If not, a `Map<String, Object>` would help.

Comment: Why do you need an array? You have three variables or constant.

Comment: Java is object oriented language. Rethink your problem in terms of Objects(Classes). Create a new Class with the required values as member variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can either make the array type generic like `Object[]` or you can just make it a String[] array and parse the integer later using `int i = Integer.parseInt(array[2]);`

Answer (score 1):

try use `interface Map<K, V>`

```
Map<String, String> values = new HashMap<>();
values.put("monthName", "April");
values.put("Year", "2014");
values.put("value", "4658");
```

or create Entity class:

```
Map<Integer, Entity> values = new HashMap<>();
values.put(0, new Entity("April", "2014", 4658));

// $entry = $values[0]
Entity entity = values.get(0);

// foreach ($values as $key => $value) {  }
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Entity> entry : values.entrySet()) {  }

public class Entity {
    private String monthName;
    private String year;
    private int value;

    // ... constructor, getters and setters
}
```

Comment: The OP wants to be able to store both `int` and `String` in the same map, not just `String`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Map to achieve the effect?

```
Map<String, String> values = new HashMap<String, String>();
values.put("monthName", "April");
...
```

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use object array and careful while fetching objects and casting.
below is eg:

```
Object date[] = {"April","2014",12};

        for (int i=0; i<date.length;i++) {
            switch (i) {
            case 0:
                System.out.println((String)date[i]);
                break;
            case 1:
                System.out.println((String)date[i]);
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println((Integer)date[i]);
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: `default: break;` is useless, you don't need it. Also, it would be better to check with `instanceof` instead of `switch`. `if(date[i] instanceof Integer) System.out.println((Integer) date[i])`